# Export Core Data from iOS app to CSV via MFmail

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using core data with an entity of "Checkins" with attributes "who, "reason", and "date". I would like to export the core data to a csv and attach/send from MFmail. I am unable to get the export to csv to work -  when I click to send the mail, the email composer works properly, but there is no csv attachment... no errors are reported. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController
    {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        let now = df.string(from: Date())

        // Establish the controller from scratch
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        // Set preset information included in the email
        mailComposerVC.setSubject(now + " - Checkins")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("\n", isHTML: false)

        // Turn core data for responses into a .csv file

        // Pull core data in
        let CoreDataResultsList = [NSManagedObject]()

        // Register the proper delegate and managed context
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        // Pull the data from core data

        do {
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Checkins>(entityName: "Checkins")
            self.items = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            } catch {
            print("Cannot fetch Date")
            }
        
        // Take the managed object array and turn it into a .csv sring to write in the file
        // In doing this, we are writing just like we would to any string
        let csvString = writeCoreObjectsToCSV(objects: CoreDataResultsList)
        let data = csvString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: false)
        mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(data!, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "GenericFilename.csv")

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    // Takes a managed object and writes it to the .csv file ..?
    func writeCoreObjectsToCSV(objects: [NSManagedObject]) -> NSMutableString
    {
        // Make sure we have some data to export
        guard objects.count > 0 else
        {

            return ""
        }

        let mailString = NSMutableString()


        mailString.append("Generic Header 1, Generic Header 2, Generic Header 3")

        for object in objects
        {
            // Put "\n" at the beginning so you don't have an extra row at the end
            mailString.append("\n\(object.value(forKey: "who")!),\(object.value(forKey: "reason")!)")
        }
        return mailString
    }
```

Comment: CoreDataResultsList is always an empty array (your data is in self.items). I would suggest you learn how to use the debugger which would have helped a lot here.

Comment: Certainly appreciate the feedback - still learning and will explore debugging.

Edit: Just doubled back on what you said and fixed the problem immediately. Much simpler than I thought, but again just a beginner so I have a lot to learn.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As Joakim suggested, the items should be retrieved from self.items not NSManagedObject as I previously had it.

WRONG WAY:

```
        // Pull core data in
        let CoreDataResultsList = [NSManagedObject]()
```

RIGHT WAY:

```
        // Pull core data in
        let CoreDataResultsList = self.items
```